# Whats the safest way to output custom JavaScript and Css code entered by the admin in the Theme Settings?

Tags: theme-development, css, javascript, security, escaping

I'm creating a theme in which I've created options for the admin to enter custom Javascript and Css code in the "Theme Settings" page (created using Options API).

Now I'm just not sure how to output this code in the best possible way. For the Css I've decided to use `wp_add_inline_style()` and update a css file, and for JavaScript I'm just echoing out the code before the `wp_footer()` tag, like so:

```
if ( $custom_js != '' ) { ?>
  <script id="theme-custom-js">
    <?php echo $custom_js; ?>
  </script>
<?php }
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

All this works great but I'm not sure if I should be using any escaping functions before simply adding the css to the file or echoing out whatever the user has entered.

I've tried `esc_html`, `esc_js` and `wp_json_encode`, but obviously these are meant to do the opposite.

I understand that the code should be safe since it's supposedly coming from the admin, but it's just that I've taken extreme measures throughout my theme and have tried to escape almost everything right before it is echoed out. So I just feel like I should somehow do the same with this.

Please let me know about this and thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Allowing user to control code is explicitly unsafe operation. As you note the purpose of sanitization is pretty much to *not* let user slip in anything executable and/or with malicious intent.

To "sanitize" executable code you would need programmatic understanding of it (code parser) and criteria engine to distinguish what is safe and what is not. For such requirements it is utopian.

Natively WordPress lets admin use JavaScript in post content. Now and then people report it as "horrible security vulnerability", but really it's just binary matter of trust — either you trust some user to input executable code or you don't. There is essentially no middle ground or "but not that code" in this case.